# Encrypt password for iisClientCertificateMappingAuthentication = keyset does not exist

Tags: iis-express, password-encryption, appcmd

When adding oneToOneMappings for IIS Client certificate mapping authentication. We want to encrypt the password for obvious reasons. But if we try to run the following script :

```
appcmd.exe set config "Default Web Site" -section:system.webServer/security/authentication/iisClientCertificateMappingAuthentication 
    /+"oneToOneMappings.[userName='testUser',password='securePassWord!1',certificate='CERTIFICATE_BLOB']" /commit:apphost
```

We get the keyset does not exist error.

```
ERROR ( hresult:80090016, message:Failed to commit configuration changes.
Keyset does not exist
```

How do we solve this?

(We run this on Windows XP)

[Reference 1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb422423%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

[Reference 2](http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/security/authentication/iisclientcertificatemappingauthentication)

[Reference 3](http://www.iis.net/learn/get-started/getting-started-with-iis/getting-started-with-appcmdexe)